# JavaScript micro optimization, 0, null, false etc

Tags: javascript, optimization, null

Hello micro optimization freak here. Two similar question.

1. I have many (400) vars that can be a string or empty, what to use when empty ? null or 0 ? Ok 0 takes the memory of an int but null is 4 chars afterall... Later I have to check with a if, like === null or whatever... The vars doesnt change, are mostly read...
2. In a script I use many boolean vars, I wonder if perform better use true false or 1 0, cos, again true is 4 chars.

I tried to benchmark myself but I can't... here is the test code:
1A:

```
<script> var t0, t1, l; var c = true;
t0 = performance.now();
var li = ["abcd1234",0,"abcd1234",0,"abcd1234",0]; //500 more of em.
l = li.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { if (li[i] !== 0 ) { c = true; } else { c = false; } }
t1 = performance.now();
console.log((t1 - t0) + " ms"); </script>
```

1B:

```
<script>var t0, t1, l; var c = true;
t0 = performance.now();
var li = ["abcd1234",null,"abcd1234",null,"abcd1234",null]; //500 more of em.
l = li.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { if (li[i] !== null ) { c = true; } else { c = false; } }
t1 = performance.now();
console.log((t1 - t0) + "ms"); </script>
```

2A:

```
<script>var t0, t1, l; var c = true;
t0 = performance.now();
var li = [true,false,true,false,true,false]; //500 more of em.
var l = li.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { if (li[i] === true ) { c = true; } else { c = false; } }
t1 = performance.now();
console.log((t1 - t0) + "ms"); </script>
```

2B:

```
<script> var t0, t1, l; var c = 1;
t0 = performance.now();
var li = [1,0,1,0,1,0]; //500 more of em.
var l = li.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { if (li[i] === 1 ) { c = 1; } else { c = 0; } }
t1 = performance.now();
console.log((t1 - t0) + "ms"); </script>
```

Test result:
800k vars per array, and the time is the average of 5 page loads.

1a: 0 TIME 11.99 ms | SIZE 5.35 MB
1b: null TIME 1.78 ms | SIZE 6.59 MB
2a: true false TIME 1.77 ms | SIZE 4.53 MB
2b: 1 0 TIME 1.78 ms | SIZE 1.64 MB

I must say that with a smaller number of vars, the differences (time and size) are smaller.

Comment: Are you trying to optimize for file size or performance?

Comment: An empty string is `""`, not `null` or `0`… :-D (*No kidding actually, not changing the value type of the variable might benefit performance substantially, so if you can avoid it by using different strings then do*)

Comment: A micro optimisation freak who cannot benchmark? Maybe that's what you should be learning next. Have you tried it?

Comment: Wait, 400 variables and you're *micro*-optimising? That's definitely [premature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation).

Comment: @sam well I don't know what optimize for, I think what is better for the user that open the page...

Comment: @Bergi yes I tryed 500 vars , but I can't tell a winner...  too different results

Comment: I forgot, in the case 1, the vars doesnt change, they are read and checked with the if.

Comment: @Jackt I meant that you should write better code with a *lot* fewer variables.

Comment: its a small db, i know it should be a real db but.....

Comment: Especially a database should know how to use *data structures* instead of just bunch of variables.

Comment: Now that you did post some benchmarks, did you actually run them? What were your results?

Answer (score 2):

The number of characters of `0` versus, `null`, versus `false` doesn't really matter from a performance perspective. The only thing they would impact would be the file size, but since GZip or other web compression will put repeat words in a dictionary, it does not matter that they appear multiple times (if you really care about performance, you would definitely use GZip or better).

Answer (score 1):

Micro optimizations are difficult for a couple of reasons:

1. It's really easy to get the benchmarks wrong.
2. The code we optimize might not be code that runs very often.
3. When optimizing for download size, we often forget that compression during transit can shrink your code better than you can.
4. We might be writing code that runs *faster* instead of code that runs *less*.

**Bad Benchmarks:**
JS engines are getting smarter. Many simple benchmarks do not replicate real-world conditions. The interpreters remove code with no side effects; I have helped fix these mistakes. Unlike a real application with hundreds of KB of scripts, markup, and CSS, an entire test may fit into the processor cache. Sample data may be sorted differently or have fewer elements or rows.

**Premature Optimization:**
We look over our code and see a complicated section that has a lot of conditions and maybe a nested loop and think, "There has to be a better way." But if that complicated code is only run once, or only when the user saves or the game starts, fixing it might not improve the experience.

**Compression:**
Gzip is better at finding identical parts of your code than you may be. When writing code for libraries, I will sometimes paste it into the Google Closure Compiler Service to see the stats on build optimization and compression. Some code size optimizations actually make the result *bigger* because it reduces compression. Try dropping your code examples into it and seeing what it says.

- [Google Closure Compiler Service](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com)

**Run Less Code:**
Look at the code and see if it needs to do work in the first place:

- Is the result stable for the inputs? Can it be cached or memoized?
- Is the result discarded quickly? Can it be throttled or debounced?

These are the optimizations that I would not consider premature. Sometimes, you can shrink the code that runs, even if it doesn't reduce the amount of code you write.

**Just Write It:**
The best plan is often to just write your code. Once you have it running, profile it to see where it spends the most time. Maybe you only need to optimize a few functions or throttle an event.

Comment: Thanks, I think that the point  is understand if optimize for size or performance. Size are easy to measure (tnx for that link). But performance ? I posted the test.

Comment: I created a set of tests for the micro-opt. https://jsperf.com/micro-array-opt-test -- test runs at 5000 elements, but even at half a million, there was negligible difference. This isn't a large enough block of code to matter.

Answer (score 0):

On my point of view if you going to clear variable that best way is define 'null'. Anyway modern browsers able to clear unused variables and garbage collector can not overfill.

Answer (score 0):

Test 1: I'd say that when there is no value, is better null than 0.
Test 2:I still can't tell a winner in elaboration time, but for the size wins 0 and 1, against true false.
I'm not happy yet...